# Ajax POST request 404 Error with WCF RESTFull apis with multi-parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I am writing Ajax POST multiparameter  request to fetch some data. I am getting 404 error.

Following is the Ajax request

```
   var ServerAuthKey = {};
   ServerAuthKey.UserID = localStorage.getItem("SessionUserID");
   ServerAuthKey.SessionID = localStorage.getItem("SessionID");
   ServerAuthKey.Result = true;
    openBusyIndicator();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ConnectionString+"/GetServerData.svc/FetchSelectedDiagDetails",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:JSON.stringify({clientAuthKey:ServerAuthKey,sUserID:loginDetailsObj.getUserName(),StartOffset:startDiagOffset.toString(),EndOffset:EndDiagOffset.toString() }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: populateData,
           error: fetcherror,

    });
```

Following is the WCF REST apis implementation on Server Side

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "FetchSelectedDiagDetails/{sUserID}/{StartOffset}/{EndOffset}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<Diag_tblData> FetchSelectedDiagDetails(AuthenticationKey clientAuthKey, string sUserID, string StartOffset, string EndOffset);
```

Following is the Request String

```
{"clientAuthKey":{"UserID":"riya","SessionID":"riyariya12282015183957","Result":true},"sUserID":"riya","StartOffset":"1","EndOffset":"20"}
```

Can any body help me to find out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

A Http 404 response means file not found.

The first thing to check is that Your variable "ConnectionString" is set correctly.

Comment: Connection string is correct. its working for other call. Only problem looks like the way I am passing parameter.

Comment: It could be that the url that is generated looks like this: "/GetServerData.svc/FetchSelectedDiagDetailsFetchSelectedDiagDetails/1/.." note the repeated FetchSelectedDiagDetails. Check Your IIS log.